# regular expression validator for a text box to accept a blank value or a single charecter 'C'

Tags: asp.net

what would be the regular expression for a regular expression validator if a text box in my web page can only accept a blank value or charecter 'C'

Thanks

Comment: So there are only 2 options for this, either blank or 'C'?  It sounds like you might be able to use a checkbox, and avoid validation/regular expressions all together.

Comment: I agree with @ataddeini, but if you must have a textbox, by "blank" do you mean an empty string, or a space character?

Answer (score 0):

It would be this:

```
^C$
```

That indicates that only a single C character will be accepted.  Leaving the field empty will also be acceptable, because RegEx validators do not flag empty fields as incorrect.